# break a long string into several lines in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, substring

I try to do substring against 1 long string and then want to put each sub string into a new line. For example, if I have a long string "1pxxxx2pxxx1pyyyyy", the result would be 3 lines as below.

```
1pxxxx
2pxxx
1pyyyyy
```

In my case, 1p and 2p are pre-defined keyword. I really appreciate any helps. Thank you.

Comment: What would be the "*rule*" where to split your string into pieces? What have you tried so far? You know you are expected to make an own attempt to solve your problem.

Comment: To achieve my goal, I tried to combine substring and carriage return but had no luck. I'll post my query next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-split`, the [string-splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split), with a positive [lookahead assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#grouping-constructs) (more details [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html)):

```
PS> '1pxxxx2pxxx1pyyyyy' -split '(?=1p|2p)' -ne ''
1pxxxx
2pxxx
1pyyyyy
```